# Codeigniter $this->db->where not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following codes in my model.

This is my original code.
I have tested that the value of my $category_id = 1

```
function getSubCategory($category_id){
    $this->db->select('id, subcategory');
    $this->db->from('subcategory');
    $this->db->where('category_id', $category_id);
    $this->db->order_by("subcategory", "asc");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

however I am encountering a problem where $this-db->where is not working.

```
function getSubCategory($category_id){
    $cat = 1;
    $this->db->select('id, subcategory');
    $this->db->from('subcategory');
    $this->db->where('category_id', $cat);
    $this->db->order_by("subcategory", "asc");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

I tried this line of code just to make sure that I am not doing any syntax error. And with these line of codes I am getting what I wanted. I wonder what makes my original code not work.

It would be a great help if someone can help. Thanks.

Comment: Enable profiler and share the created sql statement. $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);

Comment: What is being passed into `etSubCategory()`? Is it a number?

Comment: @Cronas De Se, will proceed once you replied !

Comment: @Venkatraman where should i put that line of code? Thanks.

Comment: if you are not fan of profile. add this code at end. echo $this->db->last_query();

Comment: @Venkatraman Nevermind that. I figured out where to put that profiler and this is the created sql statement SELECT `id`, `category`
FROM (`category`)
ORDER BY `category` asc

Comment: But that query is the query I was using when the page loads and it's not the query that I was calling.

Comment: I don't why but when I add that profiler it causes a bug in my page. I'll try to add the echo $this->db->last_query(); and update you.

Comment: @CronasDeSe, let us know the output. add "die("Cat id is $category_id); after function getSubCategory($category_id) {

Comment: I am using AJAX to call the method and it makes an error if I try to die.

Comment: Okay so I tried disabling the AJAX and just use a form to call the method. The result of the die is 1.

Comment: Okay now I tried the profiler when I disabled my AJAX and this is the result.  SELECT `id`, `subcategory`
FROM (`subcategory`)
WHERE `category_id` =  '1'
ORDER BY `subcategory` asc

Comment: hope you got your statement. check my answer for having chaining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem I was having is from the AJAX function that I was calling to the call the method in my model.

The answer is seen here

[AJAX not displaying result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967144/ajax-not-displaying-result/34967321?noredirect=1#comment57664968_34967321)