# AJAX not displaying result

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to populate a dropdown from the values of another dropdown so here is my ajax code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#category').change(function () {
    var category = $('#category :selected').val(); // <-- change this line
    console.log(category);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url('Ajax_test_controller/populateSubcategory'); ?>",
        data: category,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $(data).each(function(){
                $("#subcategory").append($('<option>', {
                    value: this.id,
                    text: this.subcategory,
                }));
            })
        },
        error: function(errorw) {
            alert("hi");
        }
        });
    });
});
```

This is my controller

```
public function populateSubcategory(){
    $category_id = $this->input->post('category');
    $data = $this->ajax_test_model->getSubCategory($category_id);
    echo json_encode($data);        
}
```

This is my model

```
function getSubCategory($category_id){
    $this->db->select('id, subcategory');
    $this->db->from('subcategory');
    $this->db->where('category_id', $category_id);
    $this->db->order_by("subcategory", "asc");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

This is my view

```
<div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Category : </label>
            <select name="category" id="category">
                <option value="0">Select Category</option>
                <?php
                    if(is_array($category) || is_object($category)){
                        foreach($category as $category_row){
                            echo '<option value="'. $category_row->id .'">'. $category_row->category .'</option>';
                        }
                    }

                ?>
            </select>
        <label class="control-label">Subcategory : </label>
        <select name="subcategory" id="subcategory">

        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know if there is a mistake on my syntax but whenever I try to change my model to

```
function getSubCategory($category_id){
    $cat = 1;
    $this->db->select('id, subcategory');
    $this->db->from('subcategory');
    $this->db->where('category_id', $cat);
    $this->db->order_by("subcategory", "asc");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

I get the results that I want with this model. But this is just to check if I am getting anything from my query.

My guess is that the category_id is not passed to my model. But when I checked the value of category_id, it is equal to 1.

And I don't see any problem. Thanks for the inputs on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the JQuery docs, while using POST

> The data option can contain either a query string of the form **key1=value1&key2=value2**, or an object of the form **{key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}**. If the latter form is used, the data is converted into a query string using jQuery.param() before it is sent. This processing can be circumvented by setting processData to false. The processing might be undesirable if you wish to send an XML object to the server; in this case, change the contentType option from application/x-www-form-urlencoded to a more appropriate MIME type.

In your Ajax request try this:

```
    var category = $('#category :selected').val();

...
...
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url('Ajax_test_controller/populateSubcategory'); ?>",
    data: {
    category:category
    },
    //dataType: 'json' No real reason to use JSON here
```

Comment: Wow thanks. This solved my problem. However I edited your code since it doesn't echo the values that I want and it causes an error if I put the dataType: 'json' in a comment.

Comment: Cool, anyway when making Ajax requests always check the networks tab in you browser inspector. There you can inspect the request (parameters, data etc) and the response.